# Facebook - check who shares a link

Tags: facebook

When I type name of e.g. youtube clip in facebook search I can get number of people that share this link.
Is it posibble to fetch list of people sharing given like using facebook api?

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't get who shared, only the total number. The easiest way to see the count is, for instance:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: that method is actually giving the "total count", which is actually the sum of the likes, comments and shares of that link (see my answer below for a more accurate method of getting the number of shares)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem !

> http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com

Creating Facebook apps was very easy, but now, you need to apply and ask for approval the app ... that sucks ...

Comment: that method is actually giving the "total count", which is actually the sum of the likes, comments and shares of that link (see my answer below for a more accurate method of getting the number of shares)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Facebook's FQL (Facebook Query Language), it gives you more information than the previously mentioned Graph API method, but Facebook are apparently going to turn off the FQL API on August 7, 2016. So its not going to be useful in the long term.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+comment_count%2C+like_count%2C+total_count%2C+share_count%2C+click_count+from+link_stat+where+url%3D%27stackoverflow.com%27
```

The interesting thing about this is it shows the result given by the previously mentioned Facebook Graph API request, i.e:

`http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com`

is actually giving the "total count", which is actually the sum of the likes, comments and shares of that link, the FQL method gives you the actual individual counts for comments, shares and likes.

Another method for getting the actual share count, is to use the links.getStats API call, but it appears to be undocumented, and nobody seems to know how long it will be available for.

Here's how to use it:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=stackoverflow.com&format=json
```